# Cast issue with EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, casting

I have the following user class:

```
public class CustomUser : User, IUser<int> {...}
public interface IUser<TKey> {...}
```

The class `User` is a partial class generated from my edmx (database to model method).

I'm trying to add a new user to database, but I got the error: "Mapping and metadata information could not be found for EntityType "MyNamespace.CustomUser".

He the code to add new user:

```
public void CreateUser(CustomUser user)
{
    User newUser = (User)user;
    this.MyEntities.Users.Add(newUser); <-- Line that error blows
    this.MyEntities.SaveChanges();
}
```

Why after the cast, the `newUser` keeps as `CustomUser`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`newUser` is a variable of type `User` but it points to the original `CustomUser` in memory.

If you run `newUser.GetType()` you'll get `CustomUser`.

To aovid this problem you'd need to create a new object of type user, and copy all of its properties. You can use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) or [ValueInjecter](https://github.com/omuleanu/ValueInjecter) to make it automatically, or do it by hand.

Another solution woudl be to configure the `CustomUser`in your EF model, so that it works as expected. You didn't specify how you have defined the EF model.